# Facing issue in using $.when().then() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to make sure that `getValue()` is called only after execution of `SetValueForVariable()`. I cannot modify `BindValue()` or `SetValueForVariable()`.

I tried  `$.when(BindValue()).then(getValue());`. (As i cannot change the already existing flow)
It works some times but sometimes it shows the previously set value.

I need to call getValue on `$(document).ready()`. How do I make sure `getValue()` is only called after execution of `SetValueForVariable()`.

```
//This function is inturn making call to SetValueForVariable() which is written in another file
//Cannot Change this
  function BindValue() {

    SetValueForVariable()

  }

  function getValue()
  {
    $.ajax({
    url: getRoutePath("GetPath/GetPath1"),
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
    debugger;
        data = JSON.parse(data)
        $('#txtBox').text(data.Count);

        });
   }


//Written in another file  
//Cannot change this function
function SetValueForVariable() {


//this fucntion is making server call the server method sets value of a Session Variable
   $.ajax({
   url: getRoutePath("SetPath/SetPath1"),
   type: "GET",
   async: true,
           ....

     });
  }
```

Comment: This is **not** standard JavaScript. Please flag similar posts also as "jQuery" (fixed this one for you).

Comment: [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) need a parameter, a Deffered, and your functions return nothing. You have to return `$.ajax`

Comment: Unfortunately SetValueForVariable doesn't return the result of $.ajax (and BindValue doesn't return anything either) - so there's no possibility to use promises. What does setvalueforvariable do in it's success method? maybe you could kludge something together if it does something interesting there - but, I reckon you're SOOL

Answer (score 3):

You could redefine `BindValue`, calling the original `BindValue` in your new definition after ensuring that `getValue` has been called.

**Pseudo code**

```
 var originalBindValue = BindValue;

 BindValue = function() {
      if getValue has been called 
           originalBindValue();
      else 
           call getValue and then originalBindValue() in getValue success / failure callback
 }
```

I think this would work around your *cannot modify BindValue limitation* - you don't actually need access to BindValue code here.

Comment: This is the best you can do in this case if BindValue cannot be modified directly.